# how to fetch values of while loop outside of while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query in which i am fetching many values now i want to get them outside the loop how can i get them?
this is my code

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where requests='pending'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)  {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name = $row['username'];
    $district = $row['district'];

}
}
     ?>
         <tr><td><?php echo $row['username']?></td><td><?php echo $row['district']?></td></tr>
```

Comment: Why you want them outside the loop ?
as I see, your code is always overwriting $name and $district, so after the loop you have only one value in each. You have just to put you html in the loop, and voila ...

Answer (score 0):

You can Just do direct printing inside the loop, using inline html and php like this :

```
<?php
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM users where requests='pending'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) : ?>
    <table>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['district'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```